# Absolute convergence and continuity imply uniform convergence of Fourier series to the function?

Tags: fourier-series, uniform-convergence, absolute-convergence

I encounter the following problem: 
Let $f$ be a periodic continuous function in $[0,2\pi]$ such that the Fourier of $f$ is absolute convergence, that is 
$$|a_0|+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (|a_n|+|b_n|)<\infty,$$
where $f(x)\sim a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx))$.
Does $a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx))$ converges uniformly on $[0,2\pi]$ to $f$? If the answer is affirmative, please give a reference. Thanks.

Comment: I can't comment, so I'll just answer that [absolute convergence does not imply uniform convergence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76104/does-absolute-convergence-of-a-sum-imply-uniform-convergence). See also [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513912/the-fourier-series-converges-absolutely-implies-it-converges-uniformly). Edit: Never mind; it autoconverted to a comment.